React Router Not Rendering Register Component on Route Change
I am having trouble with my React application using react-router-dom where my components are not rendering correctly when navigating to different routes. Here are the details of my setup:
App.js:
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Register from './components/Register';
import Login from './components/Login';
import Companies from './components/Companies';
import './App.css';

function App() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <div className="App">
                <header className="App-header">
                    <h1>Welcome to Medicinska Oprema App</h1>
                    <p>Your React application is running!</p>
                </header>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
                    <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
                    <Route path="/companies" component={Companies} />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </Router>
    );
}

export default App;

Register.js:
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';

const Register = () => {
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        email: '',
        password: '',
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        city: '',
        country: '',
        phoneNumber: '',
        occupation: '',
        company: ''
    });

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setFormData({
            ...formData,
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        });
    };

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        axios.post('/api/users/register', formData)
            .then(response => {
                alert('Registration successful!');
            })
            .catch(error => {
                alert('Error registering user.');
            });
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Register Component</h1>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input type="text" name="email" value={formData.email} onChange={handleChange} placeholder="Email" />
                <input type="password" name="password" value={formData.password} onChange={handleChange} placeholder="Password" />
                <input type="text" name="firstName" value={formData.firstName} onChange={handleChange} placeholder="First Name" />
                <input type="text" name="lastName" value={formData.lastName} onChange={handleChange} placeholder="Last Name" />
                <input type="text" name="city" value={formData.city} onChange={handleChange} placeholder="City" />
                <input type="text" name="country" value={formData.country} onChange={handleChange} placeholder="Country" />
                <input type="text" name="phoneNumber" value={formData.phoneNumber} onChange={handleChange} placeholder="Phone Number" />
                <input type="text" name="occupation" value={formData.occupation} onChange={handleChange} placeholder="Occupation" />
                <input type="text" name="company" value={formData.company} onChange={handleChange} placeholder="Company" />
                <button type="submit">Register</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Register;

When I navigate to http://localhost:3001/register, the page does not display the Register component. Instead, it shows the default "Edit src/App.js and save to reload" page.
What I've tried:
I have verified that the paths are correct.
I have checked that the components are correctly imported.
I have no errors in the browser console or network tab.
Project Dependencies (package.json):
{
  "name": "medicinska-oprema-frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.7.2",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.23.1",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}

I would greatly appreciate any help or suggestions on how to fix this issue. Thank you!

You are using React-Router-DOM version 6 ("react-router-dom": "^6.23.1"), which uses different routing components.

Replace Switch with the Routes component
Use the Route component's element prop and pass the routed components as JSX

import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Register from './components/Register';
import Login from './components/Login';
import Companies from './components/Companies';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <h1>Welcome to Medicinska Oprema App</h1>
          <p>Your React application is running!</p>
        </header>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="/companies" element={<Companies />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;

It is advisable to check out the Main Concepts and Upgrading from v5 migration guides for comprehensive information and details on all the breaking changes between v5 and v6.

Thank you for your suggestion. I updated App.js as per your instructions, but I am still seeing the default "Learn React" page when I navigate to http://localhost:3001/register, http://localhost:3001/login, or http://localhost:3001/companies.
I would appreciate any further advice.

@CodeExplorer Can you clarify what "Learn React" page you are referring to? Have you shared a complete [mcve] in your post?
